# AJAX wrapper for Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

### The current situation

I have implemented a Vue plugin that manages the calls to the server using queues.

I have an auto-save UI that whenever user leaves an input the Client Side code sends the UiState to the server for storing in the DB. Since the user may enter and leave many inputs in short time the Ajax Requests might not received from the server in sequence.

Since I send the complete UiState object and the server might not receive the requests in the same order as send, I might not save the last change at the server but a previous.

This is why I implemented the following plugin for Vue. It uses a Queue and if by the time the server responds to the save request a new save request has been triggered, it sends only the latest save-request.

```
import axios from "Axios"
import qs from 'qs';

export default {
    install(Vue, pluginOptions) {
        var ajs = {}; //ajax-saving

        var defaultPluginOptions = {
            indicatorElement: null
        };

        // saving flags
        ajs.isSaving = false;
        ajs.pendingSaving = false;
        ajs.pendingRequests = [];


        // the indicator element
        ajs.indicator = null;
        ajs.indicatorTitle = null;

        Vue.prototype.$ajaxSaveData = function (serverUrl, data, callback) {
            //use pending flag for the function to recall itself when it finishes
            if (ajs.isSaving) {
                ajs.pendingSaving = true;
                ajs.pendingRequests.push({ serverUrl: serverUrl, data: data, callback: callback });
                console.log('%cAjaxSaving %cThe save action is queued!', 'color:#67A9BF;', 'color:#E3DC29');
                return;
            }

            onSaveStarted();

            axios({
                    url: serverUrl,
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    data: qs.stringify(data),
                })
                .then(result => {
                    onSaveEnded();
                    if (callback) callback(true, result);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);

                    onSaveEnded(true);
                    if (callback) callback(false);
                })

        }

        // saving events
        var onSaveStarted = function () {
            ajs.isSaving = true;

            ajs.indicator.removeClass('error');
            ajs.indicator.addClass('saving');
            ajs.indicator.show();
            ajs.indicatorTitle.html("Saving");

            console.log('%cAjaxSaving %cStarted!', 'color:#67A9BF;', 'color:#7DBF67');
        }
        var onSaveEnded = function (error) {
            ajs.isSaving = false;
            ajs.indicator.removeClass('saving');

            if (error) {
                ajs.indicator.addClass('error');
                ajs.indicatorTitle.html("Error");
                console.log('%cAjaxSaving %cError!', 'color:#67A9BF;', 'color:#E60909');
            } else {
                ajs.indicatorTitle.html("Saved");
            }

            console.log('%cAjaxSaving %cEnded!', 'color:#67A9BF;', 'color:#091152');

            // execute the pending savings
            if (ajs.pendingSaving) {

                var pendingToProcess = ajs.pendingRequests;
                ajs.pendingRequests = [];
                ajs.pendingSaving = false;

                console.log('%cAjaxSaving %cExecuting Pending!', 'color:#67A9BF;', 'color:#E83CC5');

                // process all pending request found in stack.
                // skip older requests if newer are found
                var req;
                var processedRequests = [];
                while ((req = pendingToProcess.pop()) != null) {
                    if (!processedRequests.includes(req.serverUrl)) {
                        processedRequests.push(req.serverUrl);
                        var executingReq = req;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            Vue.prototype.$ajaxSaveData(executingReq.serverUrl, executingReq.data, executingReq.callback);
                        }, 0);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        var testOptions = function () {

            if (!ajs.options.indicatorElement) {
                throw ('indicator element is not set');
            }
        }

        //TODO: Remove jquery
        // Plugin initialization
        var createIndicator = function () {
            ajs.indicator = $(ajs.options.indicatorElement);
            ajs.indicatorTitle = ajs.indicator.find('span');
            if (ajs.indicatorTitle.length === 0) {
                ajs.indicatorTitle = $('<span></span>');
                ajs.indicator.append(ajs.indicatorTitle);
            }
        }
        var initialize = function () {
            //initialize options and elements needed from plugin
            ajs.options = $.extend({}, defaultPluginOptions, pluginOptions);
            testOptions();
            createIndicator();
        };


        initialize();
    }
}
```

To use this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueAjaxSaving from '@/Plugins/VueAjaxSaving'
Vue.use(VueAjaxSaving, { indicatorElement: '#ajaxIndicator' });

new Vue({
  data: {
        uiState: {....}
  },
  methods:{
    updateUiState() {
       this.$ajaxSaveData('/Page/UpdateUiState', { uiState: this.uiState }, () => this.someCallback());
    },
  }
})
```

The plugin takes as parameter an element(the jQuery selector) and updates the ui with the saving state.

### The need

I am refactoring my code to use Vuex for my state and I want the Vuex module to handle saving when something is mutated.

I want to provide my Vuex Modules a function that handles the save in the same way my Vue components did. With the ease of calling `ajaxSaveData('url',data).then(...)` from any Vuex action.

I need to update a UI part with the saving status.

### The questions

What do I have to use to fill my needs?

- Vuex plugin?
- A class function that is imported within the Module file and used as dirty as it sounds?
- A new module that contains all the saving logic ajaxSaveData? I suppose any module can dispatch it's actions.

How to update the UI for the ajaxSaveData Vuex (plugin/Class/Module)?

Answer (score 0):

A nice feature/plugin can added to **Vuex** called **subscription**. You create a plugin by simply adding a subscription function to it, like this:

```
const plugins = [
  store => {
    store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
      // your code that should happen on a mutation - it receives the full state object
    })
  }
]

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
  plugins // you have to add plugins to the Vuex store
})
```

More on **Vuex plugins**: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html

More on **Vuex subscribe**: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe

**As for the backend part**: I would add a timestamp to my request, and have the backend compare it to the currently available version - if the data received is "older" than the data in the db, then just send back the valid data.

Comment: I don't want to subscribe to a mutation or action. I need to be able to call a function of an object that can maintain an internal state. Is this possible?

Comment: So,  you have an object that stores its state, and want Vuex to save that object's state when that state is mutated?

Comment: Don't confuse this with Vuex state. Let's say local variables.